# QAF | Not able to connect to ExperiTest or pCloudy with appiumDriver but I can connect only with appiumRemoteDriver

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-android, appium-ios, qaf

I'm using switchDriver('appiumRemoteDriver') & switchDriver('chromeRemoteDriver') to connect between Web and mobile within the same scenario.

I'm not able to use switchDriver("appiumDriver") / switchDriver("iosDriver") / switchDriver("androidDriver") to connect with ExperiTest or pCloudy.

One of the issues I'm facing by using appiumRemoteDriver is that I'm not able to use QAF's mobile-support pack with common steps or are not able to execute custom commands. Eg:

```
AppiumDriver driver = (AppiumDriver) new WebDriverTestBase().getDriver().getUnderLayingDriver();
String allElements = driver.getPageSource();
```

Another option I have tried:

```
String allElements = (String) new WebDriverTestBase().getDriver().getPageSource();
System.out.println("=== Mobile ELEMENTS === : " + allElements);
```

The error I get when I use above commands:

```
Session ID: ba205277-ae7b-452d-905d-88df4231ce09
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:185) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:120) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.6.0.jar:?]
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.6.0.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebDriver.execute(QAFExtendedWebDriver.java:236) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:643) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.6.0.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebDriver.execute(QAFExtendedWebDriver.java:224) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getPageSource(RemoteWebDriver.java:468) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.6.0.jar:?]
        at com.rt.steps.rt_globals.iGetAllElements(rt_globals.java:3103) ~[test-classes/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.JavaStep.doExecute(JavaStep.java:150) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.BaseTestStep.execute(BaseTestStep.java:149) [qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.StringTestStep.execute(StringTestStep.java:127) [qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.Scenario.execute(Scenario.java:174) [qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.Scenario.scenario(Scenario.java:237) [qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:122) [surefire-testng-2.9.jar:2.9]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92) [surefire-testng-2.9.jar:2.9]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:101) [surefire-testng-2.9.jar:2.9]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164) [surefire-api-2.9.jar:2.9]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110) [surefire-booter-2.9.jar:2.9]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:172) [surefire-booter-2.9.jar:2.9]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:104) [surefire-booter-2.9.jar:2.9]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:70) [surefire-booter-2.9.jar:2.9]
msg >>Method is not implemented
```

I have read in some posts that it is better to use iosDriver or appiumDriver to get access to the driver instance.

From link: https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/issues/167
NOTE: driverClass capability will not applicable with remote driver, so if you provide driver name appiumRemoteDriver driver class will not be considered and you will get class cast exception in the above statement.

Below commands are working:

```
String drivername = TestBaseProvider.instance().get().getDriverName();
System.out.println(drivername);
// This is printing "appiumRemoteDriver"

String driverClassname =  new WebDriverTestBase().getDriver().getUnderLayingDriver().getClass().getSimpleName();
System.out.println(driverClassname);
// This is printing "QAFExtendedWebDriver"
```

************** UPDATE INFO ****************************

Error in using appiumDriver:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 0 seconds: Unable to create driver instance in 1st attempt with retry timeout of 30000 seconds. You can check/set value of 'driver.init.retry.timeout' appropriately to set retry timeout on driver initialization failure.
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.util.DynamicWait.until(DynamicWait.java:168) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.core.QAFTestBase.init(QAFTestBase.java:478) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.core.QAFTestBase.getUiDriver(QAFTestBase.java:253) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.WebDriverTestBase.getDriver(WebDriverTestBase.java:44) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebElement.<init>(QAFExtendedWebElement.java:132) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebElement.<init>(QAFExtendedWebElement.java:142) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.ElementFactory.$(ElementFactory.java:173) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.CommonStep.sendKeys_aroundBody6(CommonStep.java:114) ~[qaf-support-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.CommonStep$AjcClosure7.run(CommonStep.java:1) ~[qaf-support-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:167) ~[aspectjrt-1.9.5.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.JavaStepReporter.javaTestStep(JavaStepReporter.java:93) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.CommonStep.sendKeys(CommonStep.java:113) ~[qaf-support-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.rt.steps.rt_globals.iFillInTo(rt_globals.java:815) ~[test-classes/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.JavaStep.doExecute(JavaStep.java:150) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.BaseTestStep.execute(BaseTestStep.java:149) [qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.StringTestStep.execute(StringTestStep.java:127) [qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.Scenario.execute(Scenario.java:174) [qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.Scenario.scenario(Scenario.java:237) [qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104) [testng-6.10.jar:?]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:122) [surefire-testng-2.9.jar:2.9]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92) [surefire-testng-2.9.jar:2.9]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:101) [surefire-testng-2.9.jar:2.9]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164) [surefire-api-2.9.jar:2.9]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110) [surefire-booter-2.9.jar:2.9]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:172) [surefire-booter-2.9.jar:2.9]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:104) [surefire-booter-2.9.jar:2.9]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:70) [surefire-booter-2.9.jar:2.9]
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to create driver instance in 1st attempt with retry timeout of 30000 seconds. You can check/set value of 'driver.init.retry.timeout' appropriately to set retry timeout on driver initialization failure.
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.core.QAFTestBase$DriverInitExpectedCondition.apply(QAFTestBase.java:572) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.core.QAFTestBase$DriverInitExpectedCondition.apply(QAFTestBase.java:1) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.util.DynamicWait.until(DynamicWait.java:147) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        ... 55 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory.createDefault()Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/http/HttpClient$Factory;
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'
System info: host: 'MAVLT1059', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:10fb:ea81:8051:cf0c%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.5', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.UiDriverFactory.getDriverObj(UiDriverFactory.java:256) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.UiDriverFactory.access$4(UiDriverFactory.java:234) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.UiDriverFactory$Browsers.getDriver(UiDriverFactory.java:418) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.UiDriverFactory$Browsers.access$5(UiDriverFactory.java:407) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.UiDriverFactory.getDriver(UiDriverFactory.java:214) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.UiDriverFactory.get(UiDriverFactory.java:87) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.core.QAFTestBase$DriverInitExpectedCondition.apply(QAFTestBase.java:568) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.core.QAFTestBase$DriverInitExpectedCondition.apply(QAFTestBase.java:1) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.util.DynamicWait.until(DynamicWait.java:147) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory.createDefault()Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/http/HttpClient$Factory;
        at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.<init>(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:96) ~[java-client-7.4.1.jar:?]
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:98) ~[java-client-7.4.1.jar:?]
        at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.<init>(IOSDriver.java:90) ~[java-client-7.4.1.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.UiDriverFactory.getDriverObj(UiDriverFactory.java:254) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.UiDriverFactory.access$4(UiDriverFactory.java:234) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.UiDriverFactory$Browsers.getDriver(UiDriverFactory.java:418) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.UiDriverFactory$Browsers.access$5(UiDriverFactory.java:407) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.UiDriverFactory.getDriver(UiDriverFactory.java:214) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.UiDriverFactory.get(UiDriverFactory.java:87) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.core.QAFTestBase$DriverInitExpectedCondition.apply(QAFTestBase.java:568) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.core.QAFTestBase$DriverInitExpectedCondition.apply(QAFTestBase.java:1) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.util.DynamicWait.until(DynamicWait.java:147) ~[qaf-3.0.1.jar:?]
        ... 55 more
msg >>Timed out after 0 seconds: Unable to create driver instance in 1st attempt with retry timeout of 30000 seconds. You can check/set value of 'driver.init.retry.timeout' appropriately to set retry timeout on driver initialization failure.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `remote` from `driver.name`. Instead of using value `appiumRemoteDriver` use `appiumDriver` and set `driverClass` capability.
To use device from cloud set url provided by cloud service provider as value of `remote.server`.

For example:

```
remote.server=<url provided by cloud service provider>
```

**For ios**

```
driver.name=appiumDriver
#for ios set driverClass IOSDriver
appium.capabilities.driverClass=io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver

# you can use more meaningful name as well like below
driver.name=iosDriver
ios.capabilities.driverClass=io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver
```

**For android**

```
driver.name=appiumDriver
#for android set driverClass AndroidDriver
appium.capabilities.driverClass=io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver

# you can use more meaningful name as well like below
driver.name=androidDriver
android.capabilities.driverClass=io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
```

Refer [setting driver capabilities](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/setting_driver_capabilities.html) for more details.

Comment: I have tried above option before. I have updated with error in the main desc. NOTE: I have added cloud service provider info in appium.capabilities not in appium.additional.capabilities. Any issues with it?

Comment: Mainly I'm facing this issue with appiumDriver / iosDriver / androidDriver when I use SwitchDriver. I'm not facing this issue if I'm giving all details directly in the property file.

Comment: From the error log it looks like version compatibility issue for `selenium` and `appium` you can try using latest 3.x version `3.141.59` of selenium with appium java client `7.4.1` or latest appium 7.x version `7.6.0`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt help you are giving. I have downgraded the appium version from 7.6.0 to 7.4.1 (appium) with 3.141.59(Selenium) and it worked. Looks like the issue happens when appium is greater than 7.4.1